# How to append the text (increasing order) using regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am having a file containing following data (4 rows and 4 columns)

```
1   0.126082656 0.118439349 0.129554726 

+1  0.129733599 0.128425124 0.127376228 

+1  0.136149406 0.122109378 0.134386804 

1   0.1077886   0.108754544 0.112025117
```

Now i need to append 1: to col2, 2: to col3 3: to col4 and so on till the last column, such that the data looks like

```
1   1:0.126082656   2:0.118439349   3:0.129554726   

+1  1:0.129733599   2:0.128425124   3:0.127376228

.
.
```

I have tried using following code but i am not able to make increment

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
open(my $inp, "<train.train") or die $!;
my @amu = <$inp>;
close ($inp);
foreach my $line(@amu)
{
    if ($line =~ s/(\d+\.\d+)/1:$1/g)
    {
        print $line;
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

Please correct me to fit the desired solution.

Comment: regex if i need to add text(:1 :2 :3.....) in increasing order as column increases as given in below format                                                         1   1:0.126082656   2:0.118439349   3:0.129554726  

+1  1:0.129733599   2:0.128425124   3:0.127376228

Answer (score 0):

You can try this substitution

```
$line =~ s/(\d+\.\d+)/\1:1/g
```

**Updated Answer:**

```
open(my $inp, "< FileName") or die $!;
my $val;
my @amu = <$inp>;
close ($inp);
foreach my $line(@amu)
{
    $val=0;
    if ($line =~ s/(\d+\.\d+)/++$val != 0 ? "$val:$1:1" : ""/eg)
    {
        print $line;
    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
1   1:0.126082656:1 2:0.118439349:1 3:0.129554726:1 
+1  1:0.129733599:1 2:0.128425124:1 3:0.127376228:1 
+1  1:0.136149406:1 2:0.122109378:1 3:0.134386804:1 
1   1:0.1077886:1   2:0.108754544:1 3:0.112025117:1
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have one more query, what would be the regex if i need to add text(:1 :2 :3.....) in increasing order as column increases as given in below format                                                         1   1:0.126082656:1   2:0.118439349:1   3:0.129554726:1   

+1  1:0.129733599:1   2:0.128425124:1   3:0.127376228:1

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<= )(\S+)
```

You can try this.Replace by `\1:1` or `$1:1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/75

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it:

```
while(<DATA>) {
    my $i = 1;
    s/(\s)(\d)/"$1" . $i++ . ":$2"/eg;
    print;
}

__DATA__
1   0.126082656 0.118439349 0.129554726 
+1  0.129733599 0.128425124 0.127376228 
+1  0.136149406 0.122109378 0.134386804 
1   0.1077886   0.108754544 0.112025117
```

**Output:**

```
1   1:0.126082656 2:0.118439349 3:0.129554726 
+1  1:0.129733599 2:0.128425124 3:0.127376228 
+1  1:0.136149406 2:0.122109378 3:0.134386804 
1   1:0.1077886   2:0.108754544 3:0.112025117
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do that without a script but on the command line:

```
perl -pe "$q=1;s/(\s)(\S)/$1 . $q++ . ':' . $2/ge" your_file.txt
```